# Display form according value entry

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The folowing codes post data to a controller using the CodeIgniter jQuery Ajax method. After hit on submit the value entered display. I would like to not only display the value entered by the user but compare this value with data in database, if value entered exists in database a **form should display** if value not exist the form should not display but this value should be still displayed. I have the model that check the value but i don't know how to use in controller.

Your help is so appreciated !

**Controller**

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('get_value');

}
class Ajax_Post_Controller extends CI_Controller {

// Show view Page
public function index(){
$this->load->view("ajax_post_view");
}

// This function call from AJAX
 public function user_data_submit() {
 $data = array(
  'username' => $this->input->post('name')

   );

echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Ajax post
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".submit").click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var user_name = $("input#name").val();

 jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/ajax_post_controller/user_data_submit",
dataType: 'json',
data: {name: user_name},
success: function(res) {
if (res)
{
 // Show Entered Value
jQuery("div#result").show();
jQuery("div#value").html(res.username);

 }
 }
 });
});
});
</script>
 <?php

// Form Open
echo form_open();

// Name Field
echo form_label('User Name');
$data_name = array(
'name' => 'name',
'class' => 'input_box',
'placeholder' => 'Please Enter Name',
'id' => 'name'
 );
echo form_input($data_name);
echo "<br>";

?>
  </div>
  <div id="form_button">
   <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', "class='submit'"); ?>
  </div>
   <?php
  // Form Close
  echo form_close(); ?>
```

**model**

```
 function get_search_form() {
 $match = $this->input->post('name');
$this->db->where('name',$match);
$query = $this->db->get('transaction');
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you loaded the model using `$this->load->model('get_value')`
You can use `this->get_value` which is referring to your model

Let's say we have this simple codeigniter `User` model:

```
class User extends CI_Model{

   function __construct(){
     parent::__construct(); 
   }

   function checkUser($id){
      // here some code to check if the user exists in db
   }


   function addUser($data){
      // here some code to add users 
   }

   // ... and here other methods to do the other 'crud' operations 
}
```

And when you load the previous model inside your controller, 
you can call it for example to check if the user exists as it is shown in this example :

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();

      // load the user model
      $this->load->model('User');
   }

   function checkUser($id){
      // now make use of the 'User model'
      if(this->User->checkUser($id)){
         // display the appropriate message
      }

   }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my issue is how to integrate the checkuser function in the function that send the post value.. After user clicks the checking sould be done and value entered sould display ...

Comment: When the user click on 'check sold' use  jquery ``$.post`` to issue a post request to the desired page for example ``$.post('localhost/mysite/home.php/checkuser/1',{},function(serverResponse){
    console.log(serverResponse);
});``